# What are the accepted formats for list options in dnf/yum .repo files?

Tags: yum, repository, dnf

Some options in repository sections of dnf/yum .repo files accept a list of entries, for example, gpgkey and baseurl, but what's the corret format for passing the entries to these options?

When I tried this:

```
[c7-media]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Media
baseurl=file:///media/CentOS/
        file:///media/cdrom/
        file:///media/cdrecorder/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

There was no problem and the command "dnf repoinfo c7-media" returned the following result:

```
Repo-id      : c7-media
Repo-name    : CentOS-7 - Media
Repo-status  : disabled
Repo-baseurl : file:///media/CentOS/, file:///media/cdrom/, file:///media/cdrecorder/
Repo-expire  : 172,800 second(s) (last: unknown)
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo
```

As you can see, Repo-baseurl separates baseurls using commas, then I changed the .repo file to:

```
[c7-media]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Media
baseurl=file:///media/CentOS/, file:///media/cdrom/, file:///media/cdrecorder/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

And the output of the command "dnf repoinfo c7-media" was the same.

Can I separate the list options using commas instead of newlines in .repo files?

Also, the newline format MUST start with a space or tab at the beginning of the line, otherwise, the command "dnf repoinfo c7-media" can't parse the .repo file and returns an error.

Comment: I'd use newlines: it is easier to overview, adding/deleting is manipulating lines (special commands in most editors), if you keep it under some version control differences are obvious.

Comment: Thank you, but I just want to know, if it's OK to use commas or not.